# Strange performance of C code: more instructions executes faster than fewer ones

Tags: c, performance, loops, for-loop

I run following two codes in C using GCC compiler.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int
main()
{
    int i, j, k, l, step, count = 0;
    double duration;
    float multi;

    const clock_t begin_time = clock();

    for (step = 1; step < 10000; step++)
        for (k = 1; k < 27000; k++) {
            for (i = 1; i < 5; i++)
                for (j = 1; j < 9; j++) {
                    count++;            // INSTRUCTION-1
                }
        };

    duration = (double) (clock() - begin_time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("C program count = %d  \n", count);
    printf("clock = %f \n", duration);
}
```

The second code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int
main()
{

    int i, j, k, l, step, count = 0;
    double duration;
    float multi;

    const clock_t begin_time = clock();

    for (step = 1; step < 10000; step++)
        for (k = 1; k < 27000; k++) {
            for (i = 1; i < 5; i++)
                for (j = 1; j < 9; j++) {
                    count++;            // INSTRUCTION-1
                    multi = 9.56587458 * 8.547458748;   // INSTRUCTION-2
                }
        };

    duration = (double) (clock() - begin_time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("C program count = %d  \n", count);
    printf("clock = %f \n", duration);
}
```

Both the codes are almost same. The only difference is that the first code has only one instruction inside the loop, whereas the second code has two instructions inside the loop. Therefore, I was expecting the second code should take longer to execute. However, to my surprise, **The execution time of the first code was 22.45 seconds, whereas for the second code was 17.96 seconds. Why is the second code executed faster than the first code, even if it involves significantly more computations?**

CPU used was Intel Xeon E5-2670V 2.5 GHz 2 CPU-IvyBridge (20-cores), if this information is relevant.

Comment: For starters, you compiled with optimization disabled. Without optimization, the compiler is in a “dumb” mode and is not expected to produce efficient output.

Comment: How many times did you run your benchmark?  Was your computer *completely unoccupied* during the test?

Comment: Specify the specific version of GCC you used and all the command-line switches.

Comment: can someone please approve my edits if possible, I have many pending edits and cannot do any more edits. **I cannot see unformatted code**

Comment: There is UB due to `count++` integer overflow, with or without optimizations.

Comment: Testing at Godbolt with Clang 11.0 and GCC 10.2 with default options shows faster execution for the second version (after decreasing `step` and `k` limits by factors of 10 to stay under Godbolt limit) with Clang and slower with GCC. The generated assembly between the versions differs only in the expected ways, essentially extra `movss` instructions in the second version. So I expect the performance difference is an artifact of processor execution—having some `movss` in the instructions resulted in something else in instruction dispatching or execution happening to flow better.

Comment: I downloaded, compiled [with `-O3`], and ran both versions. The disassembly was _identical_. The execution time was: 0.000002 Note that in the 2nd example, the optimizer _could_ [and probably _did_] detect that `multi = 9.56587458 * 8.547458748;` was fixed [and loop invariant], so it would have migrated it out. Because it was set but not used, that would explain the code elimination. Indeed, if you had compiled with warnings (e.g. `-Wall`), the compiler would flag the `multi = ...` statement.

Comment: @dxiv: Easily fixed by making `count` unsigned.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Or `long long` for that matter.

Comment: An important detail  multi = 9.56587458 * 8.547458748 is resolved in compilation time, it is just a constant. And if coded is optimized that operation is probably out of the loops. This doesnt explain why 1 is slower, from my point of view both must take the same time.

Comment: ah was already pointed by @CraigEstey

Comment: @CraigEstey I have rerun these codes [with `step` going up to 1000] by replacing second instruction by `multi = 0.5*count;`. After this, the first version was executed in `2.25 s` and the second version took `3 s`.  So, probably your explanation is correct. However, I still could not understand that earlier with `multi = 9.56587458 * 8.547458748;` even if the compiler migrated this instruction out, why should the second version take lesser time? Shouldn't it be same as the first version?

Comment: @RobertHarvey at least 5 times.

Comment: From the first comment (by Eric), you're compiling _without_ optimization, so it's a bit pointless to worry about performance. Although the tests should be run several times and take the _minimum_ time, I ran the unoptimized programs twice. The times: `code1:  19.430483 code2: 20.511513` and `code1: 19.435285 code2: 18.116939`. So, we got conflicting results on two runs. As you surmised, a 19 second test is _too long_ to quibble about the variations (unrelated system loading / time slicing can overshadow the results). With `-O0`, the only asm diff was two additional `movss` in 2nd code

Comment: @EricPostpischil running twice the program on the godbolt does not make any sense as the server may have a different load at both runs.  you need to get it in one run https://godbolt.org/z/j6jErW

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the assembly output at https://godbolt.org/z/136qsc

This function:

```
double multiply(void) {
    return 9.56587458 * 8.547458748; ;
}
```

doesn't include a multiply instruction, or the constants 9.56587458 or 8.547458748.  The compiler notices that the result can be calculated at compile time, so there's no reason to have that code in the output or to execute it at runtime.  You aren't doing what you think you are doing with your two examples, so it makes sense that the one that adds no additional complexity isn't significantly slower.

Comment: You are correct, but your observation does not explain why the second function is significantly faster than the first one.

Answer (score 3):

If you compile with optimizations enabled (otherwise all performance tests do not have any sense ), the compiler will optimize all of your loops out and it will only assign the count with compile-time calculated value. Double multiplication will be optimized out (as you do not use the result at all) https://godbolt.org/z/9MebGc

But even if we change the program to force loops the expected difference will be very small (because loops will have much more instructions than the multiplication of two doubles). And it actually is:

```
void test(volatile double x, volatile double y)
{
    volatile unsigned  i, j, k, l, step, count = 0;
    double duration;
    double multi = 0.0;

    const clock_t begin_time = clock();

    for (step = 1; step < 1000; step++)
        for (k = 1; k < 27000; k++) {
            for (i = 1; i < 5; i++)
                for (j = 1; j < 9; j++) {
                    count++;            // INSTRUCTION-1
                    multi += x * y;   // INSTRUCTION-2
                }
        };

    duration = (double) (clock() - begin_time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("C program count = %d  \n", count);
    printf("clock = %f \n", duration);
    printf("%f\n", multi);
}

void test2(volatile double x, volatile double y)
{
    volatile unsigned  i, j, k, l, step, count = 0;
    double duration;
    double multi;

    const clock_t begin_time = clock();

    for (step = 1; step < 1000; step++)
        for (k = 1; k < 27000; k++) {
            for (i = 1; i < 5; i++)
                for (j = 1; j < 9; j++) {
                    count++;            // INSTRUCTION-1
                }
        };

    duration = (double) (clock() - begin_time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("C program count = %d  \n", count);
    printf("clock = %f \n", duration);
    printf("%f\n", multi);
}
 
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    test((double)rand()/rand(), (double)rand()/rand());
    test2((double)rand()/rand(), (double)rand()/rand());
}
```

and the result:

```
C program count = 863104032  
clock = 1.467764 
962658070.362825
C program count = 863104032  
clock = 1.413076 
0.000000
```

https://godbolt.org/z/hh4n18